# Ruby charting library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, graph

I need to display some charts/graphs based upon user inputs on my web aplication built using Ruby on Rails. Are there any charting libraries out there that I could use with ROR for displaying simple bar, line and pie graphs?

Answer (score 12):

There is a nice gem called

[gruff](https://github.com/topfunky/gruff)

for graphs in ruby. You'll need the fabulous [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and [rmagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) library. Since installation of the latter two is not really trivial (but not difficult, either), there's a [installation FAQ](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html) for that.

Looks something like this:

More examples of this library: http://geoffreygrosenbach.com/projects/show/5

Answer (score 7):

Down with flash and imagemagick.

Try [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com) with the lazy high charts plugin for ruby: github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts.

Comment: At least ImageMagick is released under Apache 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Or cloudsource the charts via google - here's the gem for that: https://github.com/mattetti/googlecharts

Example:

```
# console
$ ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/mattetti/googlecharts.git

# view
<img src="<%=GoogleChart.pie(['1997',10],['1998',70],['1999',20]).to_url%>">
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the aptly named [googlecharts](http://github.com/mattetti/googlecharts) gem mentioned above there are two more that use the Google Charts  API, [gchartb](http://code.google.com/p/gchartrb/) and [ruby-googlechart](http://github.com/jparker/ruby-googlechart).

For the very awesome [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) javascript charting library, looks like someone has started a rails plugin called [protovis on rails](http://github.com/ciaranj/protovisonrails), but it still looks rough and hasn't been touched in a while.

Answer (score 3):

Open Flash Chart 2 is very nice and pretty easy. You get more dynamic features (tooltips, onclick, hover, ...): looks nice :)

In this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87561/what-is-your-preferred-way-to-produce-charts-in-a-ruby-on-rails-web-application) a few more very interesting alternatives are mentioned. Of which i find the most interesting (i am not allowed to use hyperlinks -so use google :)

- flot, a jQuery based graphing library, with a rails plugin flotilla. Especially if you are already using jQuery in your Rails app, like i am.
- raphael, which looks very interesting, and also has a smaller brother gRaphael, especially for graphs/charts. A pure javascript, alas without any plugin for the moment. But that should not be too hard.

These are both javascript libraries, offering the same kind of visual appearance and interactive as the flash alternative, without the flash, which is imho a big advantage. Aside of which it even seems there are more interactive options/possibilities than the open flash chart can offer. I am going to check these out :)

I am not allowed to show more than 1 url, so Google is your friend :)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

There is another gem called scruffy that does not need rmagick & imagemagick/graphicsmagick if you want to generate only svg.

Here is the project page http://scruffy.rubyforge.org that has quite a few examples

Comment: The link seems broken, find it here https://github.com/brasten/scruffy.
It needs RMagick and Magic installed, if you wish to render to bitmap.

Comment: Scruffy seems nice and simple, a little buggy on ruby 2.6.x (misses builder and generate the wrong viewbox for SVG).

Answer (score 1):

For small graphs, there is [Sparklines](https://rubygems.org/gems/sparklines)

Comment: True. Gem page still lists that link as homepage, but it looks like it hasn't been updated in ages.

Answer (score 0):

Yui chart from [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/charts/) it works also offline. There is a ruby plugin for it, I didn't know the name of it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[Chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) looks trending at the moment and also works with Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

I've two own options:

https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_charts - if you need to build complex charts, with many examples and helpers for easier use.

https://github.com/railsjazz/peity_vanilla_rails - if you need to add sparklines charts, simple, but informative (line, bar, pie..)