# Displaying charts in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to display charts (bar, line , pie-charts etc.) in my Ruby on Rails application. I tried using Gruff and Scruffy. But found it crude and not easy to use. Then i came around googlecharts (**http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/**) Can anyone site an example, how to use Google Chart in Ruby on Rails application ? Any input on this will be helpful.

Thanks,
Bhargav

Comment: This question also has some good recommendations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775836/ruby-charting-library

Comment: Try [google visualr](http://googlevisualr.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: will add own library - https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_charts it's using Apache eCharts. Gem have useful helpers to make integration eaier with just a few steps

Answer (score 14):

https://github.com/ankane/chartkick

Create Javascript charts with one line of Ruby

Answer (score 4):

You can see other options of charts 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts

It is very easy to implement highcharts. 
Please see http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

Comment: Note that Higcharts is Free for Non-commercial

Answer (score 1):

Check out the graphing section at Ruby Toolbox: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/graphing. As already mentioned by Raji, Railscasts has a cast about charts as well, [rails cast 223](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts). There is also a [revised railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts-graphs-revised), unfortunately behind a paywall, and a railscast about [chart events in real time](http://railscasts.com/episodes/378-fnordmetric).

Answer (score 1):

I've used flot charts (http://www.flotcharts.org/) in a rails application and they worked great.  They needed very minimal configuration and displayed my time series json data (metrics data) intuitively.  Definitely recommend checking flot charts out.