# Charts library for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, charts

I am looking for a quite specific tool for generating charts, within Ruby on Rails application. I have done a research and couldn't find a solution that suits me.

Maybe you've bumped upon it and could just point me to it with a link? :)

My requirements for a solution are:

- it has to feature basic chart types
  like Pie, Bar, Stacked Bar, Line.
- it has to have basic configuration of
  a chart like legend, axis
  description.
- **it has to be able to generate and save chart into image file without
  actually rendering it in a browser**
- being a Ruby library would be nice,
  but it is not obligatory
- not being Gruff Graphing Library, I
  am looking for something more up to
  date, with less issues.

If you are aware about something, please post a link - it'll take you just a few seconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is your preferred way to produce charts in a Ruby on Rails web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87561/what-is-your-preferred-way-to-produce-charts-in-a-ruby-on-rails-web-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made a number of useful charts with the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). There are a few gems: [googlecharts](http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/), [gchartrb](http://gchartrb.rubyforge.org/). I haven't used them but they look like a good first cut.

As to not displaying it you can just make the call and save the result. No need to render, just make the call, get the URL, and fetch the file.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Google Chart API is great. I already considered doing it like this, but the problem is - sending not encrypted data. If I am missing something, or you could point me somewhere where I could read about secure communication with Google Chart API then please let me know :)

Comment: Alas, google doesn't seem to support charts over SSL. I'm curious about your threat model. You're already giving the data to google, whether SSL or not so that doesn't seem to be the big deal. If you're caching the data in any case you can server it up to visitors to your site over SSL, regardless of how google delivered it to you.

Comment: You can specify https, as in https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|2&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/sampledata?secret=A234A234A234A234

Answer (score 6):

I think, that it is what you're looking for.

http://highcharts.com/

https://github.com/loudpixel/highcharts-rails

Comment: This one cannot write an image file server-side.

Answer (score 3):

The only one that has satisfied all these conditions:

- I have been able to make it works without need of install weird dependencies
- Not has an HTML context requirement (all JS libraries)
- Not depends on GCharts (net traffic dependency)
- Exports to static graphic format

is [gerbilcharts](http://gerbilcharts.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: Does it export to png? It looks like it just renders SVG in the view.

Answer (score 3):

[Chartkick!!!](http://ankane.github.io/chartkick/)

It's super nice. =)

Comment: How to to generate and save chart into image file without actually rendering it in a browser?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I asked this question and I see new people coming and posting new answers, which his great. This small post of mine turned out to be a small compendium of available libraries.

I decided to add my two cents. Nowadays  whenever I am dealing with charts I usually use Highcharts. Highcharts is a very pleasant library by itself, but additionally there is incredible gem [highcharts_on_rails](https://github.com/stevo/highcharts_on_rails) which facilitates creating charts using DSL written in Ruby.

If you found this question and you're looking for options, consider `highcharts_on_rails`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be able to do what you want:
[Gruff](http://gruff.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response, but one of the requirements was not being Gruff Graphing Library ;))

Comment: Haha, sorry about that, not sure how I missed it.

Comment: After researching the state of graphics libraries again 9 years later .. I settled on Gruff in the end because it seems to be the only library that doesn't either need NodeJS and a full web browser, or wouldn't work differently on Windows and Linux. Gruff internally uses RMagick, which is a wrapper for ImageMagick, which works pretty much everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rchart](https://github.com/amardaxini/rchart)  for plotting various chart.

Comment: I found it very hard to get GD2 to work on windows, so this one seems linux-only and rather old.

Answer (score 0):

I am using openflashchart
http://pullmonkey.com/projects/open_flash_chart2/

you can save generated json data in database and render when needed

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply. Though I noticed that I clarified myself poorly. I need to save chart to a file on a disc like jpg or something, without rendering it :)