# How do I implement charts in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm referring to the bar charts in the background (they are actually really subtle) of the repositories here:
Example: https://github.com/search?l=ruby&q=stars%3A%3E1&s=forks&type=Repositories

What I have is a table, and I want the background of the table cells to be a bar-chart of the user's progress. Any pointers on how I get this thing done?

Comment: If you are using PHP you could render the charts with jpGraph or any other chart library and use the image as `background-image`. This is the most suitable solution I can think of.

Comment: Oh, I'll be using Ruby on Rails for this

Comment: I suggest you add the tag for Ruby on Rails. Btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397414/charts-library-for-ruby

Answer (score 28):

I would like to suggest you to use [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). It's just awesome and easy to integrate.

Example:

**HTML**:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

            }]
        });
    });
```

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/) .

Comment: Just got to know about this today, and it's awesome!

Comment: highcharts also can do maps, like Leaflet, gonna try it now.

Comment: @Rony, Highchart is free or paid..?

Comment: @bgs I'm afraid it's not free for commercial use. You can use it for free for non-commercial use http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts

Answer (score 5):

Later than my previous answer, but may be useful anyway; while gRaphaël Charting may be an outdated alternative, a more recent and nicer option may be http://chartjs.org - still without any Flash, with a MIT license, and a recently updated GitHub.

I've been using it myself since my last answer, so now I have some web apps with one and some with the other.

If you are starting a project anew, try with Chart.js first.

Answer (score 4):

Github did this using the HTML [**canvas**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas_CR/) element.

> This specification defines the 2D Context for the HTML canvas element.
>   The 2D Context provides objects, methods, and properties to draw and
>   manipulate graphics on a canvas drawing surface.

If you use a browser inspector, you see inside every list element a div with a **canvas** element.

```
<div class="participation-graph">
   <canvas class="bars" data-color-all="#F5F5F5" data-color-owner="#F5F5F5" data-source="/mxcl/homebrew/graphs/owner_participation" height="80" width="640"></canvas>
</div>
```

With CSS (z-index, position...) you can put that canvas in the background of a li element or table, in your case.

Do a [search](https://www.google.es/search?q=canvas%20jquery%20chart) about jquery pluggins that fit your requirement.

Hope this pointers help you to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2018**

Here's a simple example using **Bootstrap 4** with ChartJs. Use an HTML5 Canvas element for the chart...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <canvas id="chLine"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>     
</div>
```

And then the appropriate JS to populate the chart...

```
var colors = ['#007bff','#28a745'];
var chLine = document.getElementById("chLine");
var chartData = {
  labels: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [589, 445, 483, 503, 689, 692, 634],
    borderColor: colors[0],
    borderWidth: 4,
    pointBackgroundColor: colors[0]
  },
  {
    data: [639, 465, 493, 478, 589, 632, 674],
    borderColor: colors[1],
    borderWidth: 4,
    pointBackgroundColor: colors[1]
  }]
};
if (chLine) {
  new Chart(chLine, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
  });
}
```

[Bootstrap 4 Charts Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/3l6UhaQEhq/bootstrap-4-chartjs)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely late to the party; anyway, for those interested, picking up on Lan's mention of HTML5 canvas, you can use [gRaphaël Charting](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) which has a MIT License (instead of HighCharts dual license). It's not Bootstrap-specific either, so it's more of a general suggestion.

I have to admit that HighCharts demos seem very pretty, and I have to warn that gRaphaël is quite hard to understand before becoming proficient with it. Anyway you can easily add nice features to your gRaphaël charts (say, tooltips or zooming effects), so it may be worth the effort.

Comment: Github on this hasn't been updated for 4 years. I think it's safe to say this isn't a viable option for current web development.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I've been searching for another library myself, and I've been using http://chartjs.org since february. Still MIT license, but way nicer and easier to use. Still without any Flash requirement. I will not update this answer, but will provide another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3rd party library like [Shield UI](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/all-charts) for charting - that is tested and works well on all legacy and new web browsers and devices.