# how to make graphics in android working with rhodes?

Tags: android, graphics, rhodes

I'm having problems to make graphics in android with rhodes, the application is ready but I need to make a Graphic with the data. It's simple just like an X, Y PLOT. I got the data but I don't know how to draw lines or something like that to make the graphic.
I'm using rhodes for the app, the structure is already done but I can't find where to add Activities to make something like this.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/XY_Chart_Plot_for_Android.aspx

What I'm doing is similar to the link above but not using Java, since I want to work with rhodes. Does anyone knows how to make graphics with data in a rhodes project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use html canvas element with javascript. There's a lot of examples of this in internet.

Answer (score 0):

As rhodes uses ruby for the application and html for the view, you can use HTML, Canvas and Javascript as stated by Salvix or generate the chart as an image in ruby and integrate it with a simple img-Tag in your HTML view. When using the first method, ensure that the browser of the android version you want to run you app on supports html canvas.

See [What is your preferred way to produce charts in a Ruby on Rails web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87561/what-is-your-preferred-way-to-produce-charts-in-a-ruby-on-rails-web-application) for some ways to do it with the second method (in ruby).